# except problem while using selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

im having a problem with my code and i hope someone can help me with that

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://ofersale.ofermalls.co.il/LogoHunter/?utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_campaign=&tp=replay")
#print(driver.self.driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_name("theCode")
search.send_keys("135205")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

inputt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="javascript: CheckCode()"]')
inputt.click()

try:
    #yolo element
    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]')
except:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]')
else:
    try:
        #yolo element
        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/golf.jpg"]') 
    except:
        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/golf.jpg"]') 
    else:
        try:
            #yolo element
            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/vardinon.jpg"]')
        except:
            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/vardinon.jpg"]')
        else:
            try:
                #yolo element
                picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/miniso.jpg"]')
            except:
                picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/miniso.jpg"]')
            else:
                try:
                    #yolo element
                    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/stemanski.jpg"]')
                except:
                    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/stemanski.jpg"]')
                else:
                    try:
                        #yolo element
                        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/jump_onot.jpg"]')
                    except:
                        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/jump_onot.jpg"]')
                    else:
                        try:
                            #yolo element
                            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/timberland.jpg"]')
                        except:
                            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/timberland.jpg"]')
                        else:
                            try:
                                #yolo element
                                picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/crazy_line.jpg"]')
                            except:
                                picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/crazy_line.jpg"]')
                            else:
                                try:
                                    #yolo element
                                    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/nautica.jpg"]')
                                except:
                                    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/nautica.jpg"]')
                                else:
                                    try:
                                        #yolo element
                                        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/polgat.jpg"]')
                                    except:
                                        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/polgat.jpg"]')
                                    else:
                                        try:
                                            #yolo element
                                            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/gali.jpg"]')
                                        except:
                                            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/gali.jpg"]')
                                        else:
                                            print("error while trying to find an xpath")

#main = driver.find_element_by_id("main")

#time.sleep(5)

#sel:driver.quit()
```

this is the code and the problem is when i run the code this is what i get on the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sublime Text 3\web2", line 23, in <module>
    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]')
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sublime Text 3\web2", line 25, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]')
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\itay\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)
```

if someone know how can i fix this i will appriciate that.

thank you so much!

Comment: Either catch this exception or check whether the element exists. This happens from the `except` part, so you don't catch it. You actually are doing the same thing that caused the exception in the first place. Also, please don't just dump the whole code here. Also, just a rule of thumb, if you go that deep with indentation and if you have to copy-paste parts of your code that much, you should reconsider what you are doing and look for better ways.

Comment: The error messages says the element cannot be found yet. While it is likely that there is no such element in the page, it is also possible that the element has been loaded into the page yet. You might want to search for implicit wait for selenium for further details.

Comment: in every `except` you run exactly the same code as in `try` - so it may generate again the same error but now it is not inside `try` so it raises error. `except` doesn't catch errors in code which you have inside `except` - it would need another `try/except`. But I don't understand why you run exactly the same code. maybe you should use `sleep` to wait for this element or you should put it in `try/except` or you should use [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in Selenium

Answer (score 0):

In every `except` you run exactly the same code as in `try` - so it may generate again the same error but now it is not inside `try` so it doesn't catch it but it raises it and stops code.

For your `except` and `else` makes no sense. I think it should use `try` directly in `except` instead of `else`:

```
try:
    print('[DEBUG] checking: yolo')
    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/yolo.jpg"]')
except:
    try:
        print('[DEBUG] checking: golf')
        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/golf.jpg"]') 
    except:
        try:
            print('[DEBUG] checking: vardinon')
            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/vardinon.jpg"]')
        except:
            try:
                print('[DEBUG] checking: miniso')
                picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/miniso.jpg"]')
            except:
                try:
                    print('[DEBUG] checking: stemanski')
                    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/stemanski.jpg"]')
                except:
                    try:
                        print('[DEBUG] checking: jump_onot')
                        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/jump_onot.jpg"]')
                    except:
                        try:
                            print('[DEBUG] checking: timberland')
                            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/timberland.jpg"]')
                        except:
                            try:
                                print('[DEBUG] checking: crazy_line')
                                picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/crazy_line.jpg"]')
                            except:
                                try:
                                    print('[DEBUG] checking: nautica')
                                    picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/nautica.jpg"]')
                                except:
                                    try:
                                        print('[DEBUG] checking: polgat')
                                        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/polgat.jpg"]')
                                    except:
                                        try:
                                            print('[DEBUG] checking: gali')
                                            picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="images/gali.jpg"]')
                                        except:
                                            print("error while trying to find an xpath")
                                            picture = None

print(picture)
```

You could even use `for`-loop to make it simpler

```
picture = None # assign default value before loop

for name in ['yolo', 'golf', 'vardinon', 'miniso', 'stemanski', 'jump_onot', 'timberland', 'crazy_line', 'nautica', 'polgat', 'gali']:
    try:
        print(f'[DEBUG] checking: {name}')
        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//img[@src="images/{name}.jpg"]')
        break  # exit loop
    except:
        pass

if picture is None:
   print("error while trying to find an xpath")

print(picture)
```

You can also use special construction `for/break/else`

```
for name in ['yolo', 'golf', 'vardinon', 'miniso', 'stemanski', 'jump_onot', 'timberland', 'crazy_line', 'nautica', 'polgat', 'gali']:
    try:
        print(f'[DEBUG] checking: {name}')
        picture = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//img[@src="images/{name}.jpg"]')
        break
    except:
        pass
else:  # if `break` was not used in `for`-loop
   print("error while trying to find an xpath")
   picture = None

print(picture)
```

Answer (score 0):

The strange use of your try-catch blocks apart, the actual exception you're getting is `no such element`, which usually means that the element was not found in the DOM at the time your code made an attempt (or a couple attempts) to access it.

One thing to remember when trying to interact with web pages via code is, make sure that the element you're looking for is loaded and available in the DOM before you try to access it.

You can test whether this is indeed the cause of the error by simply letting your code "sleep" for a few seconds right after your `inputt.click()` call, depending on how long the actual page takes to load the element in your browser. And then you can decide to use the "wait" function that Selenium provides: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/